# Maven enforcer plugin - strange artifact tree for xom:xom

Tags: maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am trying to use maven enforcer plugin and get this failure because of multiple versions. Can you, please, explain how xom:xom can be inside xom:xom?

```
[WARNING] 
Dependency convergence error for xom:xom:1.1 paths to dependency are:
+-com.***:***:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-net.unicon.cas:cas-addons:1.12
    +-edu.internet2.middleware.grouper:grouperClient:2.1.0
      +-xom:xom:1.1
and
+-com.***:***:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-net.unicon.cas:cas-addons:1.12
    +-edu.internet2.middleware.grouper:grouperClient:2.1.0
      +-xom:xom:1.1
        +-xom:xom:1.0b3
```

Update 1:

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T09:29:23-08:00)
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac
```

Plugin info:

```
<plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                  <rules>
                                      <DependencyConvergence/>
                                  </rules>
                            </configuration>
                                <executions>
                                   <execution>
                                        <phase>validate</phase>
                                         <goals>
                                             <goal>enforce</goal>
                                         </goals>
                                    </execution>
                                </executions>
                       </plugin>
```

Full output of maven enforcer plugin. As you can see problem is for xom:xom and jaxen:jaxen

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (default) @ my_code ---
[WARNING] 
Dependency convergence error for jaxen:jaxen:1.1-beta-8 paths to dependency are:
+-com.some_company_name:my_code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.some_company_name:cas-code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-net.unicon.cas:cas-addons:1.12
      +-edu.internet2.middleware.grouper:grouperClient:2.1.0
        +-xom:xom:1.1
          +-jaxen:jaxen:1.1-beta-8
and
+-com.some_company_name:my_code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.some_company_name:cas-code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-net.unicon.cas:cas-addons:1.12
      +-edu.internet2.middleware.grouper:grouperClient:2.1.0
        +-xom:xom:1.1
          +-jaxen:jaxen:1.1-beta-8
            +-jaxen:jaxen:1.1-beta-6
and
+-com.some_company_name:my_code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.some_company_name:cas-code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-net.unicon.cas:cas-addons:1.12
      +-edu.internet2.middleware.grouper:grouperClient:2.1.0
        +-xom:xom:1.1
          +-jaxen:jaxen:1.1-beta-8
            +-jaxen:jaxen:1.0-FCS

[WARNING] 
Dependency convergence error for xom:xom:1.1 paths to dependency are:
+-com.some_company_name:my_code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.some_company_name:cas-code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-net.unicon.cas:cas-addons:1.12
      +-edu.internet2.middleware.grouper:grouperClient:2.1.0
        +-xom:xom:1.1
and
+-com.some_company_name:my_code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.some_company_name:cas-code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-net.unicon.cas:cas-addons:1.12
      +-edu.internet2.middleware.grouper:grouperClient:2.1.0
        +-xom:xom:1.1
          +-xom:xom:1.0b3

[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for jaxen:jaxen:1.1-beta-8 paths to dependency are:
+-com.some_company_name:my_code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.some_company_name:cas-code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-net.unicon.cas:cas-addons:1.12
      +-edu.internet2.middleware.grouper:grouperClient:2.1.0
        +-xom:xom:1.1
          +-jaxen:jaxen:1.1-beta-8
and
+-com.some_company_name:my_code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.some_company_name:cas-code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-net.unicon.cas:cas-addons:1.12
      +-edu.internet2.middleware.grouper:grouperClient:2.1.0
        +-xom:xom:1.1
          +-jaxen:jaxen:1.1-beta-8
            +-jaxen:jaxen:1.1-beta-6
and
+-com.some_company_name:my_code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.some_company_name:cas-code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-net.unicon.cas:cas-addons:1.12
      +-edu.internet2.middleware.grouper:grouperClient:2.1.0
        +-xom:xom:1.1
          +-jaxen:jaxen:1.1-beta-8
            +-jaxen:jaxen:1.0-FCS
, 
Dependency convergence error for xom:xom:1.1 paths to dependency are:
+-com.some_company_name:my_code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.some_company_name:cas-code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-net.unicon.cas:cas-addons:1.12
      +-edu.internet2.middleware.grouper:grouperClient:2.1.0
        +-xom:xom:1.1
and
+-com.some_company_name:my_code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.some_company_name:cas-code:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    +-net.unicon.cas:cas-addons:1.12
      +-edu.internet2.middleware.grouper:grouperClient:2.1.0
        +-xom:xom:1.1
          +-xom:xom:1.0b3
]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: First which Maven version do you use? Which version of maven-enforcer-plugin do you use? Can you post the full output of the WARNING of enforcer?

Comment: running mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=xom do you get the same transitive dependency tree?